# Run Firefox with some non-readable files

Tags: permissions, firefox, gui

I would like to run Firefox (installed via Ubuntu Software) on Ubuntu 20.04 while having any of the Firefox files be non-readable that are necessary for Firefox to run. So I don’t need all Firefox files to be non-readable. A single, but necessary, Firefox file being non-readable suffices. The user I would be running Firefox as is a standard user (i.e. no superuser rights).

The motivation for this is that I want to run Firefox with locked add-ons, policies.json and userChrome.css that help me prevent procrastinating. However, if I have read-access, I can just copy-paste Firefox, remove the procrastination-preventing files (since the copied files will be mutable and writeable) and run a Firefox instance without my helpful restrictions. An approach I tried is making the “firefox” binary file (i.e. usr/lib/firefox/firefox) non-readable, since I read that binaries are executable even when non-readable, but that leads to the situation in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZIUs.png) below in any tab I open.

Of course, I would also appreciate completely different solutions for the problem I am trying to solve. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: "I read that binaries are executable even when non-readable" Where did you read that? It is wrong.

Comment: Here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34294/273577 
Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: Another source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881567/5827510

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that. I retract my statement.